# Android fix small Screen with "Force CPU rendering" 2D hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

since the new Firmware Update
while Developer options "Force CPU rendering" is activated
my App appears normal for 1 second, than it shrinks to 1/8 of the display size
and is unreadable :(

Lots of users complained already. What can I do?

Without the 2D Hardware Acceleration it works just fine (like it did the last 3 years)

my Layout  Main.xml look "something" like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/widget253"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="  .......

     ...... lots of other Layouts

 </RelativeLayout>  
</TableLayout>
```

in my Manifest.xml I have also

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2"></uses-sdk>

    <supports-screens 
 android:anyDensity="false" 
 android:normalScreens="true" 
 android:largeScreens="true" 
 android:smallScreens="true" 
 android:resizeable="true">
 </supports-screens>
```

I just mention that because maybe there is the problem?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can disable hardware acceleration in your manifest:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```

Comment: Also please file a bug at http://b.android.com with repro steps so we can fix the problem.

Comment: @Entreco, Tried right now.... Still the same.
Even did put android:hardwareAccelerated="false" into my main activity just to see if that helps.... still the same :(
hardwareAccelerated="false" does not change anything.

I just found out, even without that Tag, but with support-screens "android:anyDensity="true" the app appears normals size, but than I have several other design glitches (thats why I always had anyDensity="false" .....) ... ?? how to deactivate now hardwareAccelerate WITHOUT that I have to set anyDensity = 'true' ??
Btw no prob in the simulator !

Comment: Will that FORCE CPU Rendering come implemented in any further Android Version ... or even implemented in the Firmware? Than I can throw my app away, as there are too many changes I would have to do. 
Android should keep its backwards compatibility !!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to temporarily fix a similar problem with my app with:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout p = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        p.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}
```

Since then I've changed the few parts of the app that were incompatible with GPU acceleration, and forced use of it both in the manifest and in the app. It has greatly improved the smoothness and responsiveness of the app!